# Retrieving a value from a list at specific index

Tags: list, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Firebase screenshot]

([image: Firebase Screenshot 2]

I am very new to programming so please excuse my ignorance but how would I retrieve the value 'loyalty' at category_list index 1? Using Flutter (Dart) I have tried the documentation but alas have found myself down the rabbit hole.

I have no issue with the code below when retrieving an image from the question document and I'm trying to achieve the same result.

```
    final questions = await _firestore
      .collection('questions')
      .document(getCategory)
      .collection(pullLeadership)
      .document('question')
      .get();
  newQuestion = questions.data['$questionNumber'];
```

Comment: try: category = categories.data['category_list'][1];

Comment: The single quotes are wrong. Either use backticks, or no quotes at all `newQuestion = questions.data[questionNumber];`

Answer (score 1):

Should be:
category = categories.data["category_list"][1];